# How a React function output can be added in a embed-HTML link

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Sorry if it is a dummy question.

I am trying to make a react website

I have a React function;

```
{this.state.graphNumber}
```

which returns a number of index of graphs.
**Please see the link below. e.g function returns 111**

Update: Sorry it is a embed HTML-Link not a URL link

I need to add that number into a embed html-link for showing correct graph.

```
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" "src=//plot.ly/~username/111.embed?showlink=false&modebar=false&autosize=true" ></iframe>
```

I search the internet but I could not figure out.

Thank you for advance

Comment: What do you have in `this.state.graphNumber` Is it an array, int or an object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you well, you want a dynamic URL. For that you can try something like that:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="100%"  src={`//.url-is-here/${this.state.GraphNumber}`}></iframe>
```

Edit: Add brackets around dynamic url, thanks to @DTul comment below.

Comment: Thank you @Arnaud your answer, I edited my question so might I was wrong, it should have been an embed html link. I tried your answer but did not work

Comment: @macintosh can you show your code line you wrote in iframe?

Comment: @macintosh the above answer should work. Did you use single quotes instead of `back-tick` ?

Comment: `<iframe width="100%" height="100%"  src={\`//.url-is-here/${this.state.GraphNumber}\`}></iframe>`. Dont forget brackets around the backticks.

Comment: Correction: I checked many times so now I am not getting any error after @Arnaud answer but empty frame!  inside <div> I have empty function alone `{this.state.GraphNumber}` and `iframe`  so I am getting a number but iframe returns an empty popup graph

Comment: I think you are mixing some concepts of React. You are talking about "React function" and then listing code about a property in the state. Can you please update your question by providing more details about your React component. Otherwise, we can't really help you.

Comment: @ArnaudChrist,  yes you were right I missed some concept of React, now it is working thank you all for help